# Error 500 while editing specific pages using Elementor

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

I am a newbie, I was editing my site, and got some errors, I used woocommerce create default pages tool to revert back to default pages but no luck, but now some of my pages are blank with just an old header. When I try to edit those pages using elementor, I get this "error 500. Click here for preview debug"

This is store page view that can't be edited
[image]

The preview debug is given below. Please help me.

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_id() on bool in /home/u330303233/domains/vendorbyte.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/dokan-lite/includes/Product/Hooks.php:406
> Stack trace:
> #0 /home/u330303233/domains/vendorbyte.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(324): WeDevs\Dokan\Product\Hooks->own_product_not_purchasable_notice()
> #1 /home/u330303233/domains/vendorbyte.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(348): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
> #2 /home/u330303233/domains/vendorbyte.com/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action()
> #3 /home/u330303233/domains/vendorbyte.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementorpro3171n/modules/woocommerce/documents/product.php(117): do_action()
> #4 /home/u330303233/domains/vendorbyte.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementorpro3171n/modules/theme-builder/documents/theme-document.php(156): ElementorPro\Modules\Woocommerce\Documents\Product->before_get_content()
> #5 /home/u330303233/domains/vendorbyte.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementorpro3171n/modules/theme-builder/documents/theme-document.php(173): ElementorPro\Modules\ThemeBuilder\Documents\Theme_Document->get_content()
> #6 /home/u330303233/domains/vendorbyte.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementorpro3171n/modules/theme-builder/documents/single-base.php(93): ElementorPro\Modules\ThemeBuilder\Documents\Theme_Document->print_content()
> #7 /home/u330303233/domains/vendorbyte.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementorpro3171n/modules/woocommerce/documents/product.php(133): ElementorPro\Modules\ThemeBuilder\Documents\Single_Base->print_content()
> #8 /home/u330303233/domains/vendorbyte.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementorpro3171n/modules/theme-builder/classes/locations-manager.php(364): ElementorPro\Modules\Woocommerce\Documents\Product->print_content()
> #9 /home/u330303233/domains/vendorbyte.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/astra/inc/compatibility/class-astra-elementor-pro.php(243): ElementorPro\Modules\ThemeBuilder\Classes\Locations_Manager->do_location()
> #10 /home/u330303233/domains/vendorbyte.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(324): ElementorPro\Modules\ThemeBuilder\ThemeSupport\Astra_Elementor_Pro->do_template_parts()
> #11 /home/u330303233/domains/vendorbyte.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(348): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
> #12 /home/u330303233/domains/vendorbyte.com/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action()
> #13 /home/u330303233/domains/vendorbyte.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/astra/inc/class-astra-loop.php(191): do_action()
> #14 /home/u330303233/domains/vendorbyte.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/astra/inc/class-astra-loop.php(174): Astra_Loop->loop_markup()
> #15 /home/u330303233/domains/vendorbyte.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(324): Astra_Loop->loop_markup_page()
> #16 /home/u330303233/domains/vendorbyte.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(348): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
> #17 /home/u330303233/domains/vendorbyte.com/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action()
> #18 /home/u330303233/domains/vendorbyte.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/astra/inc/core/theme-hooks.php(267): do_action()
> #19 /home/u330303233/domains/vendorbyte.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/astra/page.php(32): astra_content_page_loop()
> #20 /home/u330303233/domains/vendorbyte.com/public_html/wp-includes/template-loader.php(106): include('/home/u33030323...')
> #21 /home/u330303233/domains/vendorbyte.com/public_html/wp-blog-header.php(19): require_once('/home/u33030323...')
> #22 /home/u330303233/domains/vendorbyte.com/public_html/index.php(17): require('/home/u33030323...')
> #23 {main}
> thrown[image]

Answer (score 0):

Elementor doesn't work on WooCommerce default pages, try to create these pages manually.